# Is there any polymer 2 migration tool

Tags: migration, polymer, polymer-2.x

Is there any polymer 2 migration tool like [polyup](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polyup) because I have several elements and polyup just migrate from version 0.5 to version 1.0. 
I know polyup isn't so efficient but at least it skips the boring parts of migrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. As noted in the [Polymer 2.0-preview wiki](https://github.com/polymer/polymer/tree/2.0-preview):

> Before releasing Polymer 2.0, we'll also provide an upgrade tool to automate as many of the changes (both required and recommended) as possible.

The team hinted in Slack the tentative release date of 2.0 is early next year, so you could expect the tool well before then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Polymer linter** https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-linter with `--fix` option with `polymer-2-hybrid` mode.